# In the directed graph, What's the name of the node which does have both incoming and outgoing edges?

Tags: graph, nodes, terminology, vertices, edges

For example, what should I call to node C that is both a source and a sink?

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you link me the wikipedia link?

Comment: @code11 you should put this as an answer. Comments aren't how you answer a question.

Answer (score 0):

Taken straight from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Indegree_and_outdegree):

> If a vertex is neither a source nor a sink, it is called an *internal*

Note that there is no citation on that quote though.